# Why does my code stop running when it comes to pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I need to make a simple program with linked lists but my code just stops running.
Down below are to codes, first is the main .cpp file, and the second is header where the problematic function is defined. The code stops when it comes to assigning "new_" pointer attributes (marked with arrows). The function, as its name says, need to generate a linked list from an array, and return the head of that list.
I am using dev c++ for compiling, and he is not throwing any error or warning.

```
<main.cpp>

#include<stdio.h>
#include"LinkedList2.h"

int main(){
    node *head;

    int A[] = {2,8,12,9,7};
    int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);

    head = CreateListFromArray(A, n);

    PrintList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

```
<LinkedList2.h>

#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node_{
    int x;
    struct node_ *next;
}node;


node* CreateListFromArray(int A[], int n){
    node *head = NULL, *tmp = head, *new_;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        new_->next = NULL;                 //  <------
        new_->x = A[I];                    //  <------
        tmp->next = new_;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return head;
}

void PrintList(node *head){
    for(node *tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) printf("%d ", tmp->x);
}
```

Comment: `new_` does not point at a defined memory location. You can't derefence it without [misbehaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Discuss where you want it to point with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: A pointer points to a memory location. But, creating the variable does not create space for it to live. You must use new to create the space for which you expect it to point at. Until you've done that, you can't assign its attributes.

Comment: "Why does my code stop running when it comes to pointers?" - cos pointers are hard :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also have to change A[I] to A[i], because I doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

you need to allocate memory for each new node

```
node* CreateListFromArray(int A[], int n){
    node *head = NULL, *tmp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node *new_ = new node():
        new_->next = NULL;                 //  <------
        new_->x = A[I];                    //  <------
        tmp->next = new_;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

you also dont have a valid head pointer either, i leave that for you to sort out

note in c++ you dont need typedef any more.

Comment: It is still not working, now it stops on that line you added.
I tried also ` node *new = new node; ` , without brackets.
I made it to pass that, now the problem is ` tmp->next = new_; `. Don't know why.